# Dynamically download font file and use for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, font-awesome, webfonts, embedded-fonts

Is it possible to download a font file to use in Android and iOS via a http request.

I know I can put the file in the project statically but if I want to update just one icon and we have hundreds of apps, then updating the font file on a server and having the apps grab the new file on load would be ideal.

Is this possible in Android and iOS and how?